# How to test angular child component show when parent component form is edited

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

this child component is saved button component.
so what I want to do is that make sure the save button appears when form input field value has changed.

I can confirm that it could get `form.invalid = false` and `form.dirty = true` after form name value has changed, but Child component never shows, still `saveBtnComp = null`, `btnElmsAfterEdit = []`.

why child component never show??

in parent.component.html

```
<div>
  <save-button-component
    *ngIf="form.dirty"
    [invalid]="form.invalid"
    (saveChangesEvent)="submit()"
    (cancelEvent)="reset()"
  ></save-button-component>
</div>
```

in test case

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.value ={
       name: 'John Doe',
       age: '20'
    };
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('Save Button shows when form is edited', async(() => {

   // before edit form value
   const saveBtnBeforeEdit = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('save-button-component');

   expect(saveBtnBeforeEdit).toBeNull();

   const name = getControl('name');
   name.setValue('Stan Hansen');
   name.markAsDirty();
   fixture.detectChanges();


   // after edit form value
   fixture.whenStable().then(() => {

       const saveBtnAfterEdit = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('save-button-component');

       expect(saveBtnAfterEdit).not.toBeNull();

   });
}));

function getControl(...path: string[]): FormControl {
    return component.form.get(path) as FormControl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

I moved component.ngOnInit() to beforeEach();

I updated my code.